# params[:page] carry-over in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

In our app, there is a list of `purchase orders` which have `order items`. Both of the listing use `will_paginate`. Here is the code for `purchase orders`:

```
@orders = @orders.page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
```

Here is the code for `order items`:

```
@order_items = @order_items.page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
```

As the code shows, both of them reply on `params[:page]` to start with. The problem is that when a user is on, for example, 2nd page of the `purchase orders`, the `params[:page]` is set to `2`. Then the `order items` list will start with `params[:page] = 2` instead of page `1`. This causes no-listing of page 1 for `order items`. Is there a nice way to solve this problem caused by `params[:page]` carry-over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue by memorize params[:page] for each controller with the code below (in before_action)

```
def page_params
  key_sym = ('page_' + params[:controller].sub('/', '_')).to_sym
  if params[:page] then
    session[key_sym] = params[:page]
  elsif session[:key_sym]
    params[:page] = session[:key_sym]
  end 
end
```

The potential issue with the solution above is that we can not reset `session[key_sym]` and it may be floating around for next `index`.